# Regular Expression in c++ for control character -space

Tags: regex

Regular Expression in c++

Is there a way to check all control characters without space(tab,newline, carraige return)?

I tried couple of stuff with no success

[:cntrl:] considers all the control character including space(\n\r\t))

I would like to consider all control except space?

Are this valid way of going about doing this?

[:cntrl:]-[:space:]

Comment: can't you do this in two shifts? first time get all control characters, and second time take from the resolte all that don't have spaces.

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using.

Comment: VC++. To elaborate i dont want to lose formatting of my text while removing control characters from the given string

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any regex implementations which allow you to construct subsets of the POSIX character classes. But any string matching `^([^[:cntrl:]]|[[:space:]])*$` will fulfill your criteria. That is, each character has to be a non-control character, or a space character.

(Dunno what flavor C++ supports; I believe you should not have to backslash-escape anything, but haven't checked.)